# How to use gdal_rasterize with postgis vector?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, gdal-rasterize

I'm trying to convert a multipolygon vector layer to a raster using the GDAL tool `gdal_rasterize`. The command I am using is:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -burn -9999 PG:"dbname=db password=password" \
    auckland auckland.png
```

However, it seems my specification of the source for the postgis layer is incorrect as I get an

```
ERROR 4: 'auckland.png' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.`
```

So how do I successfully connect to postgres and export a vector as a tif? Is it possible?

Numerous other attempts have included:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -i -burn -9999 PG:"dbname=db password=" -l \
    auckland auckland.png

gdal_rasterize -b 1 -i -burn -9999 -l auckland PG:"dbname=db \
    password=password" auckland.png
```

And this one from [Roger's Rants](http://lagerratrobe.blogspot.co.nz/2009/02/raster-masking-with-gdalrasterize-and.html):

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -i -burn -9999 PG:'host=localhost dbname='unep'' \
    -sql "SELECT ST_buffer(the_geom, .12) from coastlines where name='Poland'" \
    Poland_elev.tif
```

When I use `ogr2ogr` to export the layer out of postgres as a shapefile, and then `gdal_rasterize` to convert to a `.tif` file it all works smoothly.

Using GDAL 1.11.2 version on Ubuntu 15.10.

Still no love with either:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -burn -9999 PG:"dbname=db password=pwd" \
    -l auckland auckland.tif
```

or:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -burn -9999 -l auckland PG:"dbname=db \
    password=pwd" auckland.tif
```

Comment: How does your ogr2ogr command look like, especially the PG: part?

Comment: Test the PostGIS connection part with ogr2ogr. When it is right ogr2ogr will list the layers. Use the connection string as datasource for gdal_rasterize and use the name of the desired layer as a value for -l. I suppose that your output image exists but do read the manual, png will not work `The GDAL supported output file. Must support update mode access`.

Comment: ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" auckland.shp PG:"dbname=db password=password" auckland.

In regards to png, I have been using tif but switched to png to test whether that was issue. The error message never changed and I never switched back to tif.

Comment: This command works for me on Windows with GDAL 2.1-dev. Data are multipolygons from the demo data of GeoServer. `gdal_rasterize  -i -burn -9999 PG:"dbname='my_db' host='localhost' port='5432' user='my_user' password='my_password'"  -l states -a_srs epsg:4326 -tr 0.1 0.1 output.tif` Output.tif did not exist which lead to an error with -b 1 which you used so I left it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new raster with [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html), either the `-tr` or `-ts` option must be used, and the `-b` option cannot be used.

E.g.

```
gdal_rasterize -burn -9999 -tr 0.001 0.001 PG:"..." -l auckland auckland.tif
```