# Convert ST_Union polygon to PNG file in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, png

I am working with Postgres 9.6, PostGIS 2.3 and GDAL 1.11.5. I would like to output the union of some polygons as a single PNG (or other image) file, with the polygons in black on a white background. (Not tiles - I just want an image.)

I know how to query the union of the polygons:

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM holdings WHERE town='Macclesfield';
```

But I don't know how to convert this to a PNG file. I've tried:

```
SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_Union(geom)) FROM holdings WHERE town='Macclesfield';
```

But this errors:

```
ERROR:  function st_aspng(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: select ST_AsPNG(st_union(geom)) from holdings where town='Ma... 
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think maybe I need to convert the union into a raster layer first?

Comment: You have to work with large objects! This could help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/raster-slightly-displaced-after-exporting-from-postgis-database and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78086/how-to-export-raster-from-postgis-enabled-db-as-gtiff-with-gdal-translate.

Comment: I think the approach using Python stored procedure is the cleanest, as in http://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_PLPython, although the method outlined by @Stefan is also good, if a bit black magicky for my liking. Basically, ST_ASPng produces a byte array  representing the png, but you need to actually convert those to an image in the file system, which those couple of lines of Python will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use gdal_rasterize to create an image from a vector source:

Create a view of your query in PostGIS:

```
CREATE VIEW myunion AS SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM holdings WHERE town='Macclesfield';
```

Then use gdal_rasterize from the command line:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn -9999 -tr 0.001 0.001 -l myunion PG:'host=localhost dbname=yourDBname user=usernamehere' holdings.tif
```

It might work also directly using the `-sql` statement, but I did not test that:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn -9999 -tr 0.001 0.001 -l holdings -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM holdings WHERE town='Macclesfield'" PG:'host=localhost dbname=yourDBname user=usernamehere' holdings.tif
```

Someone had a similar problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/187224/87998), maybe that can help.

If you don't need automation, you can of course use QGIS for your task.

Comment: The question was about using Postgis, not gdal.

Comment: Sure, the title says PostGIS, but the description seems not to be limited to it. He just wants to "output the union of some polygons as a single PNG". He even tells us that he uses `GDAL 1.11.5`. Also often people ask specific to one tool not knowing there might be easier solutions.

Comment: Sure. However, ST_AsPNG is a Postgis function, so keeping it within a query is arguably simpler. It probably depends what you are used to. I find writing SQL a great deal easier than scripting gdal, but I suppose it is a matter of personal taste. Everyone who uses Postgis uses GDAL, whether they know it or not :-)

Comment: True. I like your answer too and voted for it. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Would be happy to use `gdal_rasterize`. I had to call the view `myunion` not `union` to avoid a Postgres syntax error. I'm now having an issue with `gdal_rasterize` though: `ERROR 4: union.tif does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name`. Any ideas? My full command is `gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -l myunion PG:'host=localhost dbname=mydb user=myuser' union.tif`

Comment: For reference, the output of `gdal_rasterize --utility_version` is `gdal_rasterize was compiled against GDAL 1.11.5 and is running against GDAL 1.11.5`. Could it be this issue? https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2749

Comment: See the answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/187224/87998

Comment: OP happy to use GDAL, so that shuts me up :-)

Comment: @Richard I updated my answer according to the solution in the linked question.

Answer (score 7):

The key to this is to recognize that [ST_AsPNG](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsPNG.html) returns a bytea, ie a byte array, representing a png. So, you need to somehow convert those bytes to a file on the file system. There are a couple of ways of doing this as shown  [in the docs](http://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_PLPython).

The oid approach, as outlined by @Stefan, works, but requires psql and is a bit obscure, in my opinion.

The other approach, is to use Pythonu (ie, a Python stored procecure) to convert the bytea to an actual png file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_file (param_bytes bytea, param_filepath text)
  RETURNS text AS $$
    f = open(param_filepath, 'wb+')
    f.write(param_bytes)
    return param_filepath
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

After which you can do:

```
WITH png (bytes) AS
    (SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_Union(geom)) 
       FROM holdings 
       WHERE town = 'Macclesfield')
SELECT write_file(bytes, path_to_png) FROM png;
```

which is very clean.

As a note of warning, the Python stored procedure langauge is called plpythonu -- the final u stands for untrusted. As it states in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html):

> PL/Python is only available as an "untrusted" language, meaning it does not offer any way of restricting what users can do in it and is therefore named plpythonu. A trusted variant plpython might become available in the future if a secure execution mechanism is developed in Python. The writer of a function in untrusted PL/Python must take care that the function cannot be used to do anything unwanted, since it will be able to do anything that could be done by a user logged in as the database administrator. Only superusers can create functions in untrusted languages such as plpythonu

so you will want to make sure you use it in an isolated environment, if you go this route.

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out by @jpmc26, the plpythonu approach will only work **server-side**, and you will need to **install plpythonu** (which is not in the standard package), both of which means that you will need to have admin/super user privileges on the server, both of which are reasonable observations. I would argue, however, that if you don't have access to the server, once you have understood that ST_AsPNG returns a byte array, it is would be reasonably straight forward to write something client-side to consume the return value -- which could even be plain vanilla python, via psycopg2 (or anything other programming language that can call a Postgres function and write the resulting byte stream to disk locally).

For anyone wanting to go this route, in Ubuntu/Debian, you need to install the plpythonu extension, and then create the extension, which can be done with (change for your version).

```
sudo apt install postgresql-plpython-9.6
```

followed by

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

either within psql, pgadmin, or from a shell prompt of some description.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP is getting an error trying to call `ST_AsPNG`. PostgreSQL is perfectly capable of returning a `bytea` back to any client. The problem appears to be that `ST_AsPNG` requires a `raster` for input; your query won't work because it doesn't convert the `geometry` to `raster` first.

Comment: Using plpythonu also has several downsides I think should be mentioned. The biggest one is that you can only write files *on the server's file system* with this. If you want this on another machine, you might not have access or it could be a hassle. Additionally, plpythonu isn't included in PostgreSQL by default; I don't think it's even in the standard contrib packages. So to install it, you may need access to and privileges on the server. Then you'd need database privileges to `CREATE EXTENSION`. If you don't own/manage the machine where PostgreSQL is installed, this could be a real problem.

Comment: True. Will update answer tomorrow to reflect those points.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding to my comment, this could be the (untested) query:

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT ST_AsRast(ST_Union(geom)) AS rast FROM holdings WHERE town='Macclesfield')

SELECT 
  oid, 
  lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), png) As num_bytes
FROM (
        VALUES (lo_create(0),
               ST_AsGDALRaster(((SELECT ST_Union(rast) FROM foo)),'GTiff')
           )) As v(oid,png)
```

After the query has finished, you will see the number (something else than 176148) of the large object.

Use it to export the result to a PNG.

```
SELECT lo_export(176148, '/tmp/demo_rast.png')
```

Also see the [ST_AsGDALRaster](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_ST_AsGDALRaster.html) documentation and have a look at the supported raster formats ([ST_GDALDrivers](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_ST_GDALDrivers.html)).